# Editing a Design Suite Template File

Tags: 7, display-suite

I'm using the Design Module for a Drupal 7 site and have created a simple 1-column views display using the module and I want to take that template file that it has created and edit it more.

At the bottom of the layout options I am given a location of where the template should be along with the name of it, but it's not there.

[image: Display Suite Layout]

Is it possible to edit a layout (template file) that Display Suite has created? Where can I find those template files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source template file you are looking for should be called **ds-1col.tpl.php**. It is in the mentioned folder.

1. Copy the file to the **templates** folder within your theme.
2. Then rename the file to ds-1col--ds-views-account-wins-page.tpl.php
3. Make the adjustments you desire.
4. Flush your caches and you should see the changes.

Read more about views template files [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7) which function really similarly.